# how to kill hadoop jobs

Tags: hadoop, kill, jobs

I want to kill all my hadoop jobs automatically when my code encounters an unhandled exception. I am wondering what is the best practice to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Depending on the version, do:

*version <2.3.0*

Kill a hadoop job:

```
hadoop job -kill $jobId
```

You can get a list of all jobId's doing:

```
hadoop job -list
```

---

*version >=2.3.0*

Kill a hadoop job:

```
yarn application -kill $ApplicationId
```

You can get a list of all  ApplicationId's doing:

```
yarn application -list
```

Comment: Also mapred job -kill $jobId

Answer (score 18):

Use of folloing command is depreciated

```
hadoop job -list
hadoop job -kill $jobId
```

consider using

```
mapred job -list
mapred job -kill $jobId
```

Comment: Not working and results in the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JobId string : application_1470941878165_0001 is not properly formed

Answer (score 17):

Run `list` to show all the jobs, then use the jobID/applicationID in the appropriate command.

Kill mapred jobs:

```
mapred job -list
mapred job -kill <jobId>
```

Kill yarn jobs:

```
yarn application -list
yarn application -kill <ApplicationId>
```

Answer (score 4):

An unhandled exception will (assuming it's repeatable like bad data as opposed to read errors from a particular data node) eventually fail the job anyway.

You can configure the maximum number of times a particular map or reduce task can fail before the entire job fails through the following properties:

- `mapred.map.max.attempts` - *The maximum number of attempts per map task. In other words, framework will try to execute a map task these many number of times before giving up on it.*
- `mapred.reduce.max.attempts` - Same as above, but for reduce tasks

If you want to fail the job out at the first failure, set this value from its default of 4 to 1.

Comment: But this will also cause a job to fail if one node dies and its tasks fail, even if there is no Exception thrown, right? However, I believe that this is indeed the closest solution to what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Simply forcefully kill the process ID, the hadoop job will also be killed automatically . Use this command:

```
kill -9 <process_id>
```

> eg: process ID no: 4040 namenode

```
username@hostname:~$ kill -9 4040
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below command to kill all jobs running on yarn.

For accepted jobs use below command.

`for x in $(yarn application -list -appStates ACCEPTED | awk 'NR > 2 { print $1 }'); do yarn application -kill $x; done`

For running, jobs use the below command.

`for x in $(yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING | awk 'NR > 2 { print $1 }'); do yarn application -kill $x; done`